# How to make one fixed background with parallax scrolling

Tags: html, scroll, tailwind-css, parallax, parallax.js

Is it possible to have one fixed video gif page and then when I'm scrolling things just add up on that fixed video gif page.So it will be only one page but things will be adding up when user is scrolling.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

You have to use `bg-scroll`. Here an example to achieve what you want:

```
<div class="h-screen bg-cover bg-scroll overflow-auto" style="background-image: url('your_gif_here.gif')">
    Your page content
</div>
```

Now **your background is fixed and full page wide** and **your content instead can be scrolled** on top of the background.

Here a simple [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/tD7p7ukWHo) on Tailwind Play.

---

Let me know how it goes! :)